# can't reference an int inside array

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to insert an int into the array number but it wont work.

```
int middlePointx[3] = {
    350, 400, 460
};
int imHere = 0;
 imHere = 0;
joystick1.position = ccp(middlePointx[imHere].x,startingPoint1.y);
```

I get a member reference base type int is not a structure or union

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the contrary, your problem is that you *are* referencing an int, but your code tries to treat it like a point.

The expression `middlePointx[0]` gives the value `350` — that's the first element of the array `middlePointx`. So the expression `middlePointx[imHere].x` is equivalent to `350.x`. Do you see where this is going wrong? The integer 350 is not a CGPoint — it doesn't have an `x` member.

I think you just want `middlePointx[imHere]`, with no member access at all.